# What are use cases for Timeline button in Preview panel?

Tags: after-effects

I'm going through AE interface basics and trying to understand what is the Timeline button for
[image]

From my observations, it just shifts focus from Preview to Timeline panel, but isn't it easier to click anywhere on timeline panel to switch focus than trying to hit small button?

Any use cases I'm missing about this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have all your timelines closed, pressing this button will open up the composition that is visible on screen and go into the timeline of said comp.

This could be useful if you're working with dozens of precomps, lock the master-comp and go diving in the precomps. Then, when you want to return to your master-comp, simply press that button.

Comment: You know, in twenty years of using after effects, I have never yet pressed that button. Thanks for the AE Tip of the Day.

Comment: I too only found out because of this question :D